# Class reference in Java

Tags: java

Hello Guys :D
Why can't I execute the following code withoud getting a runtime exception? How should it be rewritten? I am migrating from C++ where I could easily do that I suppose :D.

```
class MyJavaClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Dog bushui_RIP = new Dog();
        Dog fellow = null;
        bushui_RIP.bark(fellow);
        fellow.bark();
    }
}
class Dog {
    public void bark(Dog buddy) {
        buddy = this;
    }
    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("I am barking!!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java pass by reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference)

Answer (score 5):

`fellow` is `null`, therefore there is no object that can `bark`.

Comment: But I assume it's assigned bushui_RIP object's reference... How should it look like?

Comment: As McDowell said, it is a reference variable passed by value to the method. You can do that in C, but not in Java.

Comment: Sorrow, can you help me to correct the code? How references are passed by reference?:D

Comment: @OneMoreVladimir Java is always pass by value.

Comment: Um... To correct the code I believe I would need to know what are you trying to achieve; currently what I understand you want simply `Dog fellow = bushui;`. Optionally, modify the `bark` method to contain `return this;` (without the assignment and the parameter), then make it `Dog fellow = bushui.bark();`. Be aware, though, that this will NOT create a new dog, both `fellow` and `bushui` will be exactly the same object. To create a new dog, simply call `new Dog();`.

Comment: You can pass references by reference by encapsulating them in a class. See my answer.

Answer (score 5):

`Dog fellow` is a reference variable, but it is passed by value to the method.

Comment: Thanks, I'm only getting started with Java, how should it look like?

Comment: @OneMoreVladimir - you will have to assign a value to the local variable explicitly: `fellow = ...`

Answer (score 2):

> Dog fellow = null;

you gotta Initialise it before you can make your dogs bark.

Answer (score 2):

Change `Dog fellow = null;` to `Dog fellow = new Dog();`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your local variable fellow. It is null when you try to call bark() of it.

When you call bushui_RIP.bark(fellow) it is indeed a pass by reference, but the reference itself is passed as value (how else). So you assign to a local variable buddy in your bark(Dog) function without touching the original reference fellow.

What is bark(Dog) supposed to do? Clone this and return a new instance of Dog or assign this as it is to a reference?

Comment: Is there a way to pass a reference by reference?:D

Comment: You could do something like this, but I don't see the sense behind it: public class Main
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Dog bushui_RIP = new Dog();
        DogReference fellow = new DogReference (null);
        bushui_RIP.bark (fellow);
        fellow.ref.bark();
    }
}

class DogReference
{
 public Dog ref = null;
 
 public DogReference (Dog d) {this.ref = d;}
}

class Dog {
    public void bark (DogReference other)
    {
        other.ref = this;
    }
    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("I am barking!!!");
    }
}

Comment: @OneMoreVladimir No. Things work differently in Java - no pointers!

Comment: @OneMoreVladimit. Perhaps if you post the C++ code you must migrate, we could take a look at it and see how to "javaficate" it.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, you cannot pass object references by reference, as you do in C++ by writing `Dog **ppDog`. You can pass the value (`this`) to the caller as a return value or in a field.

Or, you can use "the cell pattern" as I call it. Firstly, define your `Cell<T>` class that holds a reference to an object with type `T`:

```
class Cell<T> {
    public T item;

    Cell(T item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
}
```

Then, you can write:

```
private void bark(Cell<Dog> buddy) {
    buddy.item = this;
}

...

Dog bushui_RIP = new Dog();
Cell<Dog> fellow = Cell(null);
bushui_RIP.bark(fellow);
fellow.item.bark();
```

Comment: What purpose does this solve instead of simply returning the value you wish to have assigned?  This seems to make the coding more complex instead of simpler.

Comment: In this case, I agree. You should just return the value. However, there are cases that I needed to use "the cell pattern". For example, imagine that the value change has to be initiated by a foreign object. In that case, you cannot just call a function and store the result; you have to find a way to pass a reference to the reference.

Answer (score 1):

Another soltuion is to change `bark()` to be static.

```
public static void bark() {
    System.out.println("I am barking!!!");
}

((Dog) null).bark();
// is the same as
Dog.bark();
```

> I am migrating from C++ where I could easily do that I suppose

I didn't think you would easily de-reference a NULL pointer without gettting a segmentation fault which kills your application.